# alfresco - convert docx to pdf and create a new version

Tags: pdf, alfresco, docx, pdf-conversion

I' m trying to convert a docx document to pdf and store the newly created pdf file as a new version. 
This is the test code:

```
var document = search.findNode("workspace://SpacesStore/30f334f3-d357-4ea6-a09f-09eab2da7488");
var folder = document.parent

var pdf = document.transformDocument('application/pdf');
pdf.name = "tranformed-" + pdf.name;
pdf.save();

document.name = "new-" + document.name + ".pdf";
document.mimetype = "application/pdf";
document.content = pdf.content;
document.save();
```

The document ends up empty. 
Is this type of conversion possible with javaScript?

Comment: Do you have a converter active for DOCX to PDF, eg JODConverter of the paid-for transformation service add-in?

Comment: @Gagravarr am I wrong or there must be also an open office server or instance running ?

Comment: Yes, you must have LibreOffice running, but if you installed with the binary installer, the Alfresco startup script should launch LibreOffice for you. Do a ps -ef|grep soffice to see if it is running.

Answer (score 1):

This Code create new pdf from docx and created pdf stored as version 1.0

```
var document = search.findNode("workspace://SpacesStore/30f334f3-d357-4ea6-a09f-09eab2da7488");
var folder = document.parent

var pdf = document.transformDocument('application/pdf');
pdf.name = "tranformed-" + pdf.name;
pdf.save();
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I need to override the initial docx with the newly created pdf.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I need to override the initial docx document with the newly created pdf.

Comment: I need something like 

  document.content = pdf.content;
  document.save();

Comment: what is the purpose of this?

Comment: We need to watermark pdf documents. So if the user uploads a non pdf file, such as a docx file, we need to convert the docx file to pdf and then watermark the file. We do not want to create a new document (transformDocument creates a new document), we want to convert the initial docx to pdf.

Comment: check this add-on.may be helpful to you. https://addons.alfresco.com/addons/alfresco-pdf-toolkit

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your support.

The problem was assigning the pdf content.

The following code seems to work only with plain text content:

```
document.content = pdf.content;
```

Paradoxically, the following is needed when assigning pdf content to a document.

```
document.properties.content.write(pdf.properties.content);
```

Thanks.